# How can I override a virtual method of a .NET class in Python using PythonNet

Tags: python, .net, virtual, managed

I'm trying, without success, to override the virtual methods of a .NET class in a Python derived class.

**Environment**
Visual Studio 2022
Pythonnet version: 3.0.1
Python version: 3.10 64-bit.
Operating System: Windows 11
.NET Runtime: 6.0

**Details**
Given the following C# code for the .NET class:

```
namespace MyTestLib
{
   public class MyTestClass
   {
      private int _x;
      public MyTestClass(int inNumber) { SetNumber(inNumber); }

      public int GetNumber()
      {
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format(".NET MyTestClass.GetNumber: {0}", _x));
         return _x;
      }
      public void SetNumber(int inNumber)
      {
         _x = inNumber;
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format(".NET MyTestClass.SetNumber: {0}", _x));
      }

      protected virtual void OnUseNumber(int inNumber) { }

      public void UseNumber(int inNumber)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format(".NET MyTestClass.UseNumber: {0}", inNumber));
         OnUseNumber(inNumber);
      }
   }

   public class MyTestClass2 : MyTestClass
   {
      MyTestClass2() : base(55) { }
      protected override void OnUseNumber(int inNumber)
      {
         SetNumber(inNumber * 4000);
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("MyTestClass2.OnUseNumber: {0}", GetNumber()));
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried the following Python code, but the OnUseNumber is never called:

```
class MySubClass(MyTestLib.MyTestClass):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__(99)

   def OnUseNumber(self, inNumber):
      self.SetNumber(inNumber * 4000)
      print ("Python MySubClass.OnUseNumber: {}".format(self.GetNumber()))

main():
   myclass = MyTestLib.MyTestClass(10)
   print("Before use: {}".format(myclass.GetNumber()))
   myclass.UseNumber(5)
   print("After use: {}".format(myclass.GetNumber()))

   myclass2 = MyTestLib.MyTestClass2()
   print("Before use: {}".format(myclass2.GetNumber()))
   myclass2.UseNumber(5)
   print("After use: {}".format(myclass2.GetNumber()))

   mysubclass = MySubClass()
   print("Before use: {}".format(mysubclass.GetNumber()))
   mysubclass.UseNumber(5)
   print("After use: {}".format(mysubclass.GetNumber()))
```

Comment: See https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/2192.